# Searching in two sql tables

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I've got two tables in a database.

```
Factory (fid, fname, address)
```

&

```
Product (pid, pname, fid, price)
```

In the `Factory` table there's a factory named `CarFactory` and in the `Product` table there are prices of the different cars they produce.

How do I search for `CarFactory` in `fname` and get the highest price in the price column in the `Product` table in a single SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT MAX(p.price)
FROM Factory f INNER JOIN Product P ON f.fid = p.fid
WHERE f.fname = 'CarFactory'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(P.price) FROM Factory F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product P
ON P.fid = F.fid
WHERE F.fname = 'CarFactory'
```

Comment: It should be `left outer join` not `outer left join`. But I fail to see why an outer join is needed at all

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I don't need left outer join?

Comment: No, you would be better off using an INNER JOIN unless you have a compelling reason not to. @DaveJemison's answer is the one you want.